# How to get count based on column value that reset it in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the count of column value but with conditional based on other column value.
ex: Below the data where first column is identity, second column statusId , third column repeat custId, fourth column status.

```
id          statusId         CustId      status  

1           1           100         E  
2           1           100         E  
3           1           100         E  
4           2           100         S  
5           1           100         E  
6           1           100         E  
7           2           100         S  
8           1           200         E  
9           1           200         E  
10          2           200         S  
11          2           200         S  
12          1           200         E  
13          2           200         S
```

I have `used Row_Number()` function but it didn't help to achieve it.

```
select case when Status = 'S' then 0
    when Status = 'E' then sum(case when Status = 'E' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by Id asc) end  as cnt
from cust
```

Expected Result: I want the result in below format using select query (not any loop).

```
CusId   ExpectedCount  
100     2              -- there are two rows with status E before last S
200     1              -- There is one row with status E before last S
```

To achieve above result, i am counting row that having status E and reset it back to 0 for status S and final count of status E should be returned prior last status S.

Actual result: I am getting count of Status value 'E' and count is not getting reset, its continue to count.
Ex.

```
custId Id Status ExpectedCount
100    1  E      1
100    2  E      2
100    3  E      3
100    4  S      0
100    5  E      4
100    6  E      5
100    7  E      6
```

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 2):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

You can use a cumulative sum to define the groups and then use `row_number()`:

```
select custid, id, status,
       (case when status = 'S' then 0
             else row_number() over (partition by custid, grp, status order by id)
        end) as expectedcount
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when status = 'S' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by custid order by id) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d162837d67316d7b24db52a8d0d9c67f) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: still giving wrong count for status 'E'  data 1           1           100         E
2           1           100         E
3           1           100         E
4           2           100         S
5           1           100         E
6           1           100         E
7           2           100         S  after executing query  100         1           E      1
100         2           E      2
100         3           E      3
100         5           E      4
100         6           E      5
100         7           S      0
100         4           S      0

Comment: i need count 2 as last row status as S and before two rows having status E

Comment: @SachinMalviya, it's hard to understand your first comment to Gordon.  You may want to edit your question and add a new expectation that you have.  In the meantime, I just ran Gordon's answer against your data in the original question, and it meets the output of both of your expectations listed.

Comment: I have edited my question and expectation to more understandable.

Comment: @SachinMalviya . . . If you change the question, then you will not get any working answers.

Comment: I haven't changed question, only changed expectation result and input data.

Comment: @SachinMalviya . . . This produces the result set that you explicitly say that you want in the first four versions or so of the question.

Comment: I am looking expected result as mentioned